# Why declare and instantiate temp object in constructor instead of real object?

Tags: java, constructor, objectinstantiation

Forgive me if this has an answer somewhere; I didn't really know what to search for... Also, my terminology may be off (declare, instantiate, etc) as I am still learning Java and OOP.

I was reading the textbook: Data Structures and Abstractions, 3rd Ed by Frank Carrano (Chaper 20: Dictionary Implementation), and I came across a pretty standard looking class containing a private inner class. But there is something about the methodology I don't quite get.

I am having a difficult time understanding why you would declare an object (or array of objects) as a field in the outer class, then in the constructor, instantiate a temp object and initialize the field as the temp object rather than just instantiating the attribute itself in the constructor.

**EDIT:** I added the type parameter back into the code... K & V are used for key and value in this case since we are working with dictionaries. I don't know if that is important to the question or not...

I have rewritten the code in question here, renaming classes and such so they aren't so localized:

```
public class OuterClass<K, V> implements SomeInterface<K, V>
{
     private InnerClass<K, V>[] foo;                  // Declare array of inner class object
     private final static int CAPACITY = 10;    // Initial Array Capacity

     // Outer Class Constructor
     public OuterClass()
     {
          InnerClass<K, V>[] tempFoo = (InnerClass<K, V>[])new InnerClass[CAPACITY];
          foo = tempFoo;
     }

     // ...

     private class InnerClass<S, T>
     {
          // Inner Class Constructor
          private InnerClass()
          {
               // ...
          }

          // ...
     }
}
```

As mentioned, I tried to get rid of any specific details in the code, as I don't think they are relevant to the question. Is there any reason why you wouldn't just do this in the outer class constructor:

```
foo = (InnerClass[])new InnerClass[CAPACITY];
```

instead of:

```
InnerClass[] tempFoo = (InnerClass[])new InnerClass[CAPACITY];
foo = tempFoo;
```

Comment: I don't see any. The cast is useless too.

Comment: Would `InnerClass` happen to be a type parameter in the actual code? (A bunch of things in this code don't work if `InnerClass` is a type parameter, but perhaps those things are different in the actual code too.)

Comment: The term "type parameter" is reserved for the use of generics. Do you mean generic type parameters - usually written as single capital letters?

Comment: The OuterClass and InnerClass are a type parameters, , I guess I could add that back into the code as it is probably important in this case...

Comment: OuterClass and InnerClass themselves cannot be type parameters, but they can have type parameters.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Sorry, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is enough:

```
foo = new InnerClass[CAPACITY];
```

**UPDATE after generics edit of OP:**

With generic type parameters the situation changes because you use a raw type on the right side. In this case casting is necessary, and you get a compiler warning because the cast cannot be type-safe. So we then have:

```
foo = (InnerClass<K, V>[]) new InnerClass[CAPACITY];
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Also, the casting is present in the book, which is why I put it here, although it is probably more implementation detail that could have been left out.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier Casting is completely unnecessary because the types of assignment left and right are exactly the same.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier You are right, type parameters are important to give you a proper answer, see my edit.

Comment: Yet with or without type params, the temp local variable is as useless.

Comment: Right, I know the type parameters and casting were related ( I don't know why I left out one but not the other) but I didn't think either had anything to do with the temp variable.

Comment: And indeed it doesn't. The cast you have was just a distraction from the main point of your question, and that point doesn't at all depend on the existence of type parameters.

Answer (score 3):

There's no purpose for it in the code you posted.  However there often can be a use-case for using this general method, if instantiation of the object might throw an Exception and you want to handle it.  Consider something like this:

```
private final Image image;

public MyClass() {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("myImage.png"));
}
```

This results in a compiler error because I haven't dealt with the possible `IOException`.  So I have to do something like below, meaning I need the intermediary variable:

```
public MyClass {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("myImage.png"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        //Perform logging, whatever
    }
    this.image = image;
}
```

... So, just because it's meaningless for the code you pasted, don't think there's never a use for such a technique.  Of course, this is only really the case for `final` variables.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, as Meno said. It doesn't make any sense.